# Sort data from mysql using select option tag for multiple page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

My website is navigated using GET method and this is the skeleton of index.php file

```
<?php
 include ('header.html');
 include ('main-content.html');
 include ('footer.html');
?>
```

In header.html contains dropdown menu (select option tag) to sort information based on city chosen like this:

```
<select onchange="sortResult(this.value)">
        <option value="">Please select city</option>
        <option value="City 1">City 1</option>
        <option value="City 2">City 2</option>
        <option value="City 3">City 3</option>
</select>
```

Here is the JS function also in header:

```
<script>
function sortResult(str)
{
  if (str=="")
  {
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
   return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","main-content-city.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Here is my main-content.html:

```
<div id="result">
  Content displayed here
</div>
```

This code is working but it only works for main-content.html page. If i navigate to another page let say child-content.html, it won't work. What should i alter the JS code to work for this case?

Here is my child-content.html page:

```
<div id="result">
  Content displayed here
</div>
```

Comment: what's different on the other page? We have no idea. Have you checked for errors in console?

Comment: main-content.html and child-content have different information but data can be sorted by city. So apply this JS only work for one page. I think I need add some condition or some code in the current JS for this to work however, i can't find anyway to make it work

Comment: if other page is in a different directory level, your ajax path won't be valid. Is that the problem?

Comment: There is no problem with path. But this line of code: `xmlhttp.open("GET","/main-content-city.php?q="+str,true); xmlhttp.send();` This is basically telling that content within id=result of main-content.html will be replaced with content from main-content-city.php. If I navigate to chid-content.html page, it won't work for the code above

Comment: inspect the request in browser console network tab and make sure the target element exists also

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `<div id="result">` to the body of child-content.html

On line 6 of your Javascript you have this

`document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";`

Which is looking for an element with the ID "result". If you don't have one of those on your page, the code will not work

Comment: This part `xmlhttp.open("GET","main-content-city.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();` only work for main-content-city.php. What about child-content-city.php?

Comment: @GiangNguyen you are using a relative URL for the AJAX request. Are main-content.html and child-content.html being loaded at the same level? You may need to change the AJAX request to

`xmlhttp.open("GET","/main-content-city.php?q="+str,true); xmlhttp.send();`

Comment: Yes, for testing purpose, i put them in the same level.

Comment: Do you get anything in `<div id="content">` on child-content.html ?

Comment: main-content-city.php will be replaced in main-content.html. child-content-city.php will be replaced in child-content.html. Do i need to add these line to js as well so it will be: `xmlhttp.open("GET","/child-content-city.php?q="+str,true); xmlhttp.send(); xmlhttp.open("GET","/main-content-city.php?q="+str,true); xmlhttp.send();` ???

Comment: That may be a potential solution. However, I would recommend extracting it into a function that takes the value and the current page to GET the appropriate content

Comment: By adding: `xmlhttp.open("GET","/child-content-city.php?q="+str,true); xmlhttp.send();` it aborted the first one and only run the last statement which is: `xmlhttp.open("GET","/main-content-city.php?q="+str,true); xmlhttp.send();`

Comment: It sends only last ajax request. Is there any if statement for it to work. Just like this: if (main-content.html loaded){run this xmlhttp.open("GET","/main-content-city.php?q="+str,true); xmlhttp.send();} else{run this: xmlhttp.open("GET","/child-content-city.php?q="+str,true);}???

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the DOM element ID "result" in present in the child-content.html page

Comment: I did have id="result" for my child-content page. However, this line of javascript code: `xmlhttp.open("GET","main-content-city.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send(); ` only work for main-content-city.php page. What about child-content-city.php page?

Comment: The request may be cached, please try xmlhttp.open("GET","main-content-city.php?q="+str+"&_"+new Date().getTime(),true); xmlhttp.send();